# Hiding or removing completely an ImageButton with jQuery by its attribute and not its ID

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an aspx page that contains the same User Control in two different places. Now there is one ButtonImage that is rendered twice with the same ID but has a different attribute that I'm adding dynamically on page PreLoad.

```
<asp:ButtonImage ID="buttonID" runat="server" myAttribute="attr1"/>
<asp:ButtonImage ID="buttonID" runat="server" myAttribute="attr2"/>
```

How can I remove with jQuery one of the two buttons, let's say the one with myAttribute="attr1"...?

Comment: `$('[myAttribute="attr2"]').remove();` will do that.

Comment: Didn't work..... maybe because ButtonImage is a server control?

Comment: @Gloria id be unique. you two id with same name

Comment: I understand that ID must be unique but how can I render the same ButtonImage twice from the same User Control that exists two times on the same page and have two different ID.... Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding your "special attribute" dynamically anyway, you could make your life easier by instead adding a specific class (like "removable").

You could then hide all elements with that class with:

```
$(".removable").hide()
```

Comment: that is right, but there are custom jquery selectors which can be used for such a case.

Comment: agreed with your comment above. I just pointed out what I though was an easier way to identify elements, especially as the OP said that this "magic attribute" was under their control